# African king walks into a bar

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> An African king walked into a bar wearing a military hat. Only one third of his abs were trained – this was no Romeo. The radio was playing Latin music without any mention of a sun god. His hands were trembling as he ordered his drink.

What did he order?

Comment: King shaka? Shaking the glass and shaka

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Working from other people's answers and putting everything together:

He ordered a ...

> **shake**.

There is ...

> a pattern in the text, which, with a bit of wordplay gives four similar words ending in a vowel: The African king is Zulu chief **Shaka**. The military hat is a **shako**. The third of the trained abs are a two-pack, and Tupac Shakur minus R ("Romeo") is **Shaku**. The Latin music may be Shakira's, who, without the sun god Ra, is **shaki**. His hands were trembling or **shaky**.
>
>  Combining the stem "shak" with the last remaining vowel "e" gives **shake**.

Comment: Oh heck, I had a couple of those and thought of doing something like this, but good for you for putting it all together! +1

Answer (score 5):

To expand on this:

An African king walked into a bar wearing a military hat.

> Maybe this is Shaka (Zulu) wearing a [PAC-Cap](http://www.militarypridegroup.com/clothing/hats/world-war-ii-veteran-pac-hat-usa-made.html) as shown here.

Only one third of his abs were trained –

> One third of a six pack is a two pack (thanks to @Chris); so he’s a Two-PAC Shaka.

this was no Romeo.

> So he’s a Capulet, which rearranges to El-Tupac (or Le Tupac, for the French).

The radio was playing Latin music without any mention of a sun god.

> A famous Latin singer is Shakira, minus the Egyptian sun god Ra leaves Shaki.

His hands were trembling as he ordered his drink.

> This means he was shaking, so he was a Shaker.

Putting it all together, he was an

> El-Tupac Two-Pack Shaker Shaka listening to Shaki(ra)! (Say that five times fast!)

I agree that the most likely drink is @Chris’, that being

> A Shot, based on his ultimate demise.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> Sounds like something to do with Tupac. One third of a six pack of abs would be a two pack, also he was black and one of the most popular rappers ever which fits African king. He was also incredibly popular with Latin Americans. 
> Unfortunately I don't really follow rap and I am not familiar with much of his music so I'm not sure about the rest. Maybe he just ordered a shot, which would make him tremble because he was killed in a drive-by shooting.